# How to find available bluetooth devices in range?

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, android-bluetooth

I am trying to find all the available bluetooth devices in a range. But I am getting only one device I am using it in thread in run method. I already checked many links for this problem on it but could not resolve this issue. 
Here is my code

```
  public void run() {


if(service != null) {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    service.registerReceiver(this.bReceiver, filter);
        bluetooth.startDiscovery();
}

}
class BluetoothReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetooth.getBondedDevices();

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                int rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
       Log.d(TAG, device.getName());
    }
    }

    if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    String uuid = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID);
    int rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
    Log.d(TAG, device.getName());
    }
    }

}
```

In Addition I want rssi value of each found device, but please ignore the syntax

Answer (score 4):

This is how I **search for Bluetooth devices** in an `Activity` and show their name and mac-address in a `ListView`. Apart from displaying the devices in a `ListView`, you can do practically anything with the discovered `BluetoothDevice` object.

**FindBluetoothActivity.java**

```
public class FindBluetoothActivity extends Activity {

    private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
    private ListView mLvDevices;
    private ArrayList<String> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_bluetooth);

        mLvDevices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDevices);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);        
        registerReceiver(mBtReceiver, filter); 

        // Getting the Bluetooth adapter
        mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(mBtAdapter != null) {
            mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Starting discovery...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth disabled or not available.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mBtAdapter != null) {
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        unregisterReceiver(mBtReceiver);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mBtReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mDeviceList.add(device.getAddress() + ", " + device.getName()); // get mac address

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDeviceList);
                mLvDevices.setAdapter(adapter);
            } 
        }
    };
}
```

**Layout** .xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".FindBluetoothActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvDevices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Android Manifest.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bluetoothexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.bluetoothexample.FindBluetoothActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Additional information:

- Make sure Bluetooth is **enabled** on your device
- Add permissions `android.permission.BLUETOOTH` and `android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` to your Manifest.xml file
- Make sure to **unregister** your broadcast-receiver when destroying the `Activity`
- Keep in mind that the Bluetooth devices in range **need to be discoverable** to be found by your application. Enabling bluetooth on them alone may not be enough. It is very often the case that some kind of "discoverable" mode needs to be enabled by the user before the device can be discovered by other devices.
- Be aware that the **range** in which devices are discoverable via Bluetooth is usually around **10m** indoors and around **50m** outdoors

Comment: But if you see my code...it is same like yours...i do not see any difference then why my code is not working

Comment: What exactly is not working in your code? Is onReceive(...) being called?

Comment: the problem is sometime the application gets hangs after reaching in this broadcast reciever dont know why and other major issue is I get only one active bluetooth device instead I want all avaible active bluetooth devices...

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that there are more devices to be discovered? Are they in a bluetooth-mode where they can be discovered? Have you considered adding each found device to a list like I do in my code?

Comment: yes I check it by keeping two other devices near this app and with bluwtooth mode on...No I have not tried but I do not think that listview makes much difference

Comment: Well it might be the case that you are overseeing devices that are discovered because you only make logcat outputs. Thats why id suggest a list or at least a toast message.

Comment: no,actually I create a json out of it with each call, so It is pretty clear....similar like keeping in list

Comment: Allright. One last try: Have you considered removing this action from the intentfilter: filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);

Comment: Yes, I just tried not working ....but one stranget thing is it usually hangs only in Nexus 5, any inputs

Comment: I recommend you copy my example code and see if both devices are listed when using my code. If so, your code is somehow invalid. If you get the same issue, it's probably because of your device(es). I just tested my code listing 3 bluetooth devices, it worked.